# Redirct to previous url & redirect from controller not working on https server

Tags: admin-controller

Here is button for controller action

```
$block->addButton('generate_label', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Generate label'),
            'onclick'   => "setLocation('{$block->getUrl('*/logistics/labelNormal')}')",//if message use: "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('*/yourmodule/crazy')}')",
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
```

This is the controller action where i am trying to redirect to previous page.

```
public function labelNormalAction() {   //label action

        $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');

        $this->createLabelAction($order_id,false);

        $this->_redirectReferer();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: also tried  $refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');  but its not return url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
 Use current url as paramter (get paramter )  when  $this->_redirectReferer() not workin

```
$currentUrl = urlencode(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
    $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?');
    $block->addButton('generate_label', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Generate label'),
        'onclick'   => "setLocation('{$block->getUrl('*/logistics/labelNormal')}?current_url=$currentUrl')",//if message use: "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('*/yourmodule/crazy')}')",
        'class'     => 'go'
    ));
}
```

get current url form request and set redirect

```
 public function labelNormalAction() {   //label action

    $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $redirectUrl = urldecode($this->getRequest()->getParam('current_url'));

    $this->createLabelAction($order_id,false);

    if($redirectUrl) {
     $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
        return $this;
    } else {
      $this->_redirectReferer();
      return;

    }

}
```

Comment: only use this solution when  $this->_redirectReferer(); not work